# Italicize Book and conference titles and place titles of websites in quotation marks in Bibliography list

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I am using `isprs.bst`, available here (http://www.isprs.org/documents/orangebook/LATEX/ISPRSguidelines_authors_latex.zip), and would like to have books in the list of references to appear in ***italics***, titles of websites placed in quotation marks and title of conference proceedings italicized using author year citation style. So far I am not successful, here is my working example:

```
\documentclass{isprs}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}     %Bib entry
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{ISPRS_References.bib}
@BOOK{58_Hastie_2011,
    title={The Elements of Statistical Learning: Data Mining, Inference, and Prediction},
    author={Hastie, T. and Tibshirani, R. and Friedman, J.},
    publisher={Springer},
    year={2011},
    month={4},
    edition={2nd},
    series = {Springer Series in Statistics}
}
@misc{OpenCV_RF_2014,
 author = {OpenCV},
 title = {{Random Trees}},
 howpublished = "\url{http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/ml.html}",
 year = {2014},
 note = "[Accessed: 20-11-2014]",
 }
 @conference{6_Bargiel_2010,
  title={Land Use Classification with High-Resolution Satellite Radar for Estimating the Impacts of Land Use Change on the Quality of Ecosystem Services},
  author={Bargiel, D. and Herrmann, S. and Lohmann, P. and S{\"o}rgel, U.},
  booktitle={Proceedings of ISPRS TC VII Symposium: 100 Years ISPRS},
  pages={68--73},
  year = {2010},
  editor =       {Wagner, W. and Sz{\'e}kely, B.},
  volume =       {XXXVIII},
  address =      {Vienna, Austria},
  month =        {July},
  publisher =    {IAPRS},
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\title{Test}
\author{Me}
\maketitle
 Changes in a scene \citep{OpenCV_RF_2014} can be monitored \citep{6_Bargiel_2010} regularly and on demand~\citep{58_Hastie_2011}. 
\bibliographystyle{isprs}
\bibliography{ISPRS_References}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome, you are referring to a journal template file as well as a bst file. The journal decided (for unknown reasons) that the bibliography should look that way. There is not much use in changing that. They will simply ignore it. My suggestion would be to ask the editors of the journal for further help on the matter.

Comment: Please indicate where the files `isprs.cls` and `isprs.bst` might be obtained from. Note also that your question purports to be about how to italicize the title of a book, yet the example entry you provide is of type `@article`, not `@book`. Please edit your posting to eliminate this conflict.

Comment: I have written to the conference organizers but so far a response is not forthcoming :(

Answer (score 1):

I ran into similar difficulty using `isprs.bst`.

My solution: edit `isprs.bst`. I now get the following in italics: titles of books, journal names (for article entries) and conference proceeding names.

You can get my version of `isprs.bst` at https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51087803/isprs.bst

I made 3 edits:
(1) to the function that formats conference proceeding names:

```
FUNCTION {format.in.ed.booktitle}
{ booktitle empty$
    { "" }
    { editor empty$
        { "In: \emph{" booktitle * "}" * } %emphasises the booktitle for bibtex items:  inproceedings, incollection and conference 
        { "In: " format.editors.reverse * ", \emph{" * booktitle * "}" * } %emphasises the booktitle for bibtex items:  inproceedings, incollection and conference 
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

It should work for items of the type @inproceedings, @conference and @incollection.

(2) In the `article` function replaced `journal "journal" duplicate$ item.check` with

```
journal "journal" duplicate$ item.check emphasize
```

(the `emphasize` function was already defined in the isprs.bst - it emphasizes the top item on the stack, which in this case is the journal name)

(3) In the `book` function I replaced `format.btitle "title" output.check` with

```
format.btitle "title" output.check emphasize
```

(this emphasizes just book titles, if I wanted to emphasize titles in a thesis or a few other things then I could have put `emphasize` inside `format.btitle`)

Websites? I didn't do anything for these because `isprs.bst` doesn't include a specific function for urls.